# MULE 4 : STORED PROCEDURE : Executing mule flow to run stored procedure returns "The index 1 is out of range"

Tags: stored-procedures, mule4

I am trying to execute a stored procedure in using MULE 4.

It expects two inputs, one is a table value parameter and another is an integer.
For the table value parameter, i am using SQLServerDataTable and specifying the tvpName using the public method setTvpName. After that I add the column metadata and add rows with the provided Arraylist of values.

In the DB:Stored Procedure component I use the syntax
`CALL [database_name].[stored_procedure_name(:argument1,:argument 2)]`

where argument 1 is the TVP and argument 2 is the integer.

But I get the error :

```
Message               : The index 1 is out of range.
Error type            : DB:QUERY_EXECUTION
```

Any ideas on how to better debug the issue or solve it is appreciated.

Comment: Please add more details of how the arguments are constructed. The flow and the data used would be helpful.

Comment: @aled I will try to create a local project and share details.